# how can I get the text data of a div without the child divs text data - with php xpath?

Tags: php, text, xpath

```
<div class="date">
  <div class="rating">good</div>
  Movie Review - Mar 24, 2013
</div>

<div class="date">
  Movie Review - Mar 23, 2013
</div>
```

What xpath query will get the "Movie Review .." part without the rating div content (where it says good).  Sometimes the rating div is present sometimes not.

I tried this sort of thing when I get a div node into `$reviewnode:`

```
  $thedate = $xpath->query('text()[1]',$reviewdate)->item(0) ;
```

but it catches the rating div contents too.

The parsed doc is html5.

Comment: I wonder how that catches the rating div too sometimes. You might want to check how you obtain all `$reviewdate` context nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return the divs' text children that contain the string "Movie":

```
//div[@class = "date"]/text()[contains(., "Movie")]
```

If you just want the first non-whitespace text node, you can use

```
//div[@class = "date"]/text()[normalize-space(.) != ''][1]
```

Comment: That worked but can I do it without referencing the text in the divs - eg I may not know what text will be in there - in either parent or child div.  Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the first text-node child that is not a white-space only node:

```
// xpath: text()[normalize-space(.)][1]

$thedate = $xpath->query(
    'text()[normalize-space(.)][1]', $reviewdate
)->item(0);
```

Results (`var_dump($thedate->data)`):

```
string(39) "\n      Movie Review - Mar 24, 2013\n    "
string(39) "\n      Movie Review - Mar 23, 2013\n    "
```

Additionally as you're looking for a value, you might want to retrieve the string value directly:

```
// xpath: normalize-space(text()[normalize-space(.)])

$thedate = $xpath->evaluate(
    'normalize-space(text()[normalize-space(.)])', $reviewdate
);
```

Results (`var_dump($thedate)`):

```
string(27) "Movie Review - Mar 24, 2013"
string(27) "Movie Review - Mar 23, 2013"
```

I hope this is helpful. See as well the [Online Demo](http://eval.in/15474) and the code-example in full:

```
<?php
/**
 * how can I get the text data of a div without the child divs text data - with php xpath?
 *
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/q/15838487/367456
 * @link http://eval.in/15474
 */
$buffer = <<<BUFFER
<html>
    <div class="date">
      <div class="rating">good</div>
      Movie Review - Mar 24, 2013
    </div>

    <div class="date">
      Movie Review - Mar 23, 2013
    </div>
</html>
BUFFER;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($buffer);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xpath->query('/*/body/div[@class = "date"]') as $reviewdate) {
    $thedate = $xpath->query('text()[normalize-space(.)][1]', $reviewdate)->item(0);
    var_dump($thedate->data);

    // string:
    $thedate = $xpath->evaluate('normalize-space(text()[normalize-space(.)])', $reviewdate);
    var_dump($thedate);
}
```